# JobScheduler.schedule() returns zero when using setPersisted(true)

Tags: android, android-jobscheduler

I am unable to successfully schedule a JobSchedulerService using [`setPersisted(true)`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html#setPersisted(boolean)). I have `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` permission in my AndroidManifest.xml. The error I get is:

```
system_process W/JobSchedulerService: Not scheduling this Job(job:<job_id>/<package_name>.MyJobService) before NTP established:1467230016977
```

Does anyone know what is causing this? If I run my app again and just comment out `setPersisted(true)`, everything works. Relevant code:

```
final JobInfo job = new JobInfo.Builder(MyJobService.JOB_ID, new ComponentName(context, MyJobService.class))
        .setRequiredNetworkType(JobInfo.NETWORK_TYPE_ANY)
        .setPeriodic(PERIOD_MILLI)
        .setPersisted(true) // If I remove this line, it works fine
        .build();

JobScheduler jobScheduler = (JobScheduler) context.getSystemService(Context.JOB_SCHEDULER_SERVICE);
        int returnVal = jobScheduler.schedule(job);
```

And my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<service
        android:name="<package_name>.MyJobService"
        android:permission="android.permission.BIND_JOB_SERVICE"
        android:exported="true"/>

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
```

Comment: Just to confirm, your `<uses-permission>` element is outside your `<application>` tag?

Comment: @ianhanniballake that is correct